# TCPDF Insert a page in the middle of an existing PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF (and TCPDI) to add a PDF to another. I have no problem if I want to join the new PDF at the end of my existing document, but I can't insert it at page 5 for example.

Here is my code :

```
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('/my_pdf.pdf');
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
    {
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage($i);
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);  

        if ($i == 6)
        {
           $pdf->AddPage();
           $pageTarifs = $pdf->setSourceFile('/pdf_to_insert.pdf');
           $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);
           $tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage($pageTarifs);
           $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);            
        }        
    }
```

I got this error : **TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: Pagenumber is wrong! (Requested 6, max 1)**

What I am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it !

You have to put again : **$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('/my_pdf.pdf');** after the other setSourceFile();

```
 if ($i == 6)
 {
     $pdf->AddPage();
     $pageTarifs = $pdf->setSourceFile('/pdf_to_insert.pdf');
     $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);
     $tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage($pageTarifs);
     $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);       

     $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('/my_pdf.pdf');     
 }
```